# Entity Framework update-database prefixes tables

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I am running the update-database command in VS to create tables in a DB for a project developed by someone else.  For some reason, when i run the command, all the tables are prefixed with my domain\username.  The same also happens for one of my collegues, meaning we now have two sets of tables!  Any idea how we stop this happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on when you are not a database owner and the object names are not schema-qualified.  So either run the migration as a database owner, or specify a schema in the model configuration to force all the objects into the `dbo` schema.